# What is emacs MRev mode?

Tags: css, emacs

I could not find anything relevant after searching "MRev", so I hope someone can offer a tip.

Here is a picture below, viewing `.css` code in `Text` mode with `Flyspell` minor mode. `MRev` does not disappear when changing files, so it appears to be a minor mode.
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is `magit-auto-revert-mode`. You can disable it by following expression.

```
(magit-auto-revert-mode -1)
```

Comment: In general, modes that add an indicator to your modeline can be identified using `C-h m` (`describe-mode`) and searching in the resulting `*Help*` buffer for the indicator text, in this case `MRev`.

Comment: Or if you actually want to leave `magit-auto-revert-mode` enabled but just don't want it to spam your mode-line, you can use something like [`smart-mode-line`](https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/smart-mode-line).

Comment: I think, this makes it in smart-mode-line: `(add-to-list 'rm-excluded-modes " MRev")`